# Memcached service could not start on windows

Tags: php, memcached

I am trying to run the memcached services on the windows but it popups error. See following image for details:

[image]

I tried to run it by cmd first then it also does not work with following command:

```
c:/memcached/memcached.exe -d start
```

[image]

I am using windows 7, 64 bit with apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the version like Memcached 1.4.5 Windows (64-bit)

See for more information below link for Download the memcached-amd64.

http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/08/25/Memcached-1.4.5-for-Windows

Regards,
Sekhar

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the community edition of [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/), which has a memcached compatibility mode and a decent installer.